# Hadoop Raw comparator

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement the following in a Raw Comparator but not sure how to write this?

the tumestamp field here is of tyoe LongWritable.

```
if (this.getNaturalKey().compareTo(o.getNaturalKey()) != 0) {
                return this.getNaturalKey().compareTo(o.getNaturalKey());
            } else if (this.timeStamp != o.timeStamp) {
                return timeStamp.compareTo(o.timeStamp);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
```

I found a hint here, but not sure how do I implement this dealing with a LongWritabel type?
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id3548156

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Is natural key a timestamp stored as a long?

Comment: no Natural key is a id and of type Text

Answer (score 1):

Let say i have a CompositeKey that  represents a pair of (String stockSymbol, long timestamp).
We can do a primary grouping pass on the stockSymbol field to get  all of the data of one type together, and then our "secondary sort"  during the shuffle phase uses the timestamp long member to sort  the timeseries points so that they arrive at the reducer partitioned  and in sorted order.

```
public class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable<CompositeKey> {
    // natural key is (stockSymbol)
    // composite key is a pair (stockSymbol, timestamp)
    private String stockSymbol;
    private long timestamp;
......//Getter setter omiited for clarity here
@Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.stockSymbol = in.readUTF();
        this.timestamp = in.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(this.stockSymbol);
        out.writeLong(this.timestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CompositeKey other) {
        if (this.stockSymbol.compareTo(other.stockSymbol) != 0) {
            return this.stockSymbol.compareTo(other.stockSymbol);
        } 
        else if (this.timestamp != other.timestamp) {
            return timestamp < other.timestamp ? -1 : 1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Now the CompositeKey comparator would be:

```
public class CompositeKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {

    protected CompositeKeyComparator() {
        super(CompositeKey.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable wc1, WritableComparable wc2) {
        CompositeKey ck1 = (CompositeKey) wc1;
        CompositeKey ck2 = (CompositeKey) wc2;

        int comparison = ck1.getStockSymbol().compareTo(ck2.getStockSymbol());
        if (comparison == 0) {
            // stock symbols are equal here
            if (ck1.getTimestamp() == ck2.getTimestamp()) {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (ck1.getTimestamp() < ck2.getTimestamp()) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            return comparison;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about way to compare LongWritable type provided by hadoop ?
If yes, then the answer is to use `compare()` method. For more details, scroll down [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/LongWritable.java).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to correctly implement RawComparator is to extend [WritableComparator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java) and override `compare()` method. The WritableComparator is very good written, so you can easily understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented from what I see in the `LongWritable` class:

```
/** A Comparator optimized for LongWritable. */ 
  public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {
    public Comparator() {
      super(LongWritable.class);
    }

    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
                       byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
      long thisValue = readLong(b1, s1);
      long thatValue = readLong(b2, s2);
      return (thisValue<thatValue ? -1 : (thisValue==thatValue ? 0 : 1));
    }
  }
```

That byte comparision is the override of the `RawComparator`.